# proplem in updating JLabel in for loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, jlabel, settext

The idea of my program is to select one name from a list that saved before in other JFrame. I'd like to print in the label all names one after the other with small delay between them, and after that stop at one of them. The problem is that `lbl.setText("String");` doesn't work if there is more than one `setText` code.

Here is the part of my code :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (RandomNames.size != 0) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            int rand = (int)(Math.random() * RandomNames.size);   
            stars.setText(RandomNames.list.get(rand));

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException err)
            {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        int rand2 = (int)(Math.random() * RandomNames.size);
        stars.setText(RandomNames.list.get(rand2));
        RandomNames.list.remove(rand2);
        RandomNames.size = RandomNames.list.size();

    }

    if (RandomNames.list.size() == 0)
    {
        last.setText("\u062A\u0645 \u0638\u0647\u0648\u0631 \u062C\u0645\u064A\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u0645\u0627\u0621 \u0627\u0644\u062A\u064A \u0641\u064A \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0626\u0645\u0629 !");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a loop or `Thread.sleep`. Just use a `javax.swing.Timer`. The following will cause 30 *iterations* occurring every 1000 milliseconds. You can adjust the code in the `actionPerformed` accordingly to what you wish to happen every so many milliseconds.

```
int count = 0;
...
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (count == 30) {
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        } else {
            int rand = (int) (Math.random()* RandomNames.size);   
            stars.setText(RandomNames.list.get(rand));
            count++;
        }
    }
});
timer.start();
```

If you want you can just set up the `Timer` in the constructor, and `start()` it in the `actionPerformed` of another button's listener.

See more at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)